# How do I know if HANDLE object been initialized?

Tags: c++, window, mutex, handle

I'm programming in C++ for Windows, and I have a `HANDLE` object to a mutex defined as:

```
static HANDLE Instance_Mutex;
```

I want to check whether this `HANDLE` is initialized by a mutex object or not; i.e is the code:

```
Instance_Mutex = CreateMutex(NULL,FALSE,NULL);
```

already been called.

If it is just lock it, and if not, create the mutex on this `HANDLE` and then lock it. What is the appropriate way to do it then?

Does the `HANDLE` object have a specific value when it has not yet been created?

Comment: @Niall: Why would that matter?

Comment: @Niall: Which variation? No recent compilers have bugs in that area I'm aware of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `HANDLE` is a global, then it will be zero initialized (i.e. it will be `nullptr`).

It would be superior style, however, to explicitly initialize it to `nullptr`.

Incidentally `nullptr` is also what `CreateMutex` returns on failure.  So this invariant (`nullptr` if the `HANDLE` isn't a mutex) will be maintained even then.

Comment: The actual declaration is lacking, it's unclear at which scope it's declared, but given the `static` I can't come up with a scope in which it would _not_ be zero-initialized.

Comment: is initiazling the HANDLE as nullptr is the same as writing: HANDLE = 0?

Comment: `HANDLE` is a pointer type.  This question is flagged as C++.  Using `0` or the macro `NULL` as null pointer constants is proscribed since C++11, which introduced [`nullptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr).

Comment: It would be much better to initialize it with `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` and compare to that.  `HANDLE` is _not_ a pointer type (except maybe to the compiler, for the moment), it is an opaque type, which is free to change from one version of the OS to the next.

Comment: `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` and `NULL` are **not** the same value.  There are functions that return a `HANDLE` and return `NULL` on failure, such as [`CreateMutex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/desktop/ms682411(v=vs.85).aspx).  Others that return a `HANDLE` and return `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` on failure, such as [`GetStdHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/desktop/ms683231(v=vs.85).aspx).  Some, such as [`CreateIoCompletionPort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363862(v=vs.85).aspx) actually use both for different `HANDLE` parameters.

Comment: Moreover, `HANDLE` explicitly **is** a pointer type: ["This type is declared in WinNT.h as follows: `typedef PVOID HANDLE;`"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx)  I.e. nothing about your comment is correct.